# C++ Help，a memory access error when using memset in a three-dimensional array instantiate with a custom class template

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++and I'm learning it now,but I meet a problem when I tried to using memset in an 3D array class I defined.
Here's the defination of the class.

```
template <class T>
class CArray3D
{
    T*** array;
    int l1;
    int l2;
    int l3;
public:
    CArray3D(int l1,int l2,int l3):l1(l1),l2(l2),l3(l3){
        array = new T**[l1];
        for(int i = 0;i < l1;++i)
        {
            array[i] = new T*[l2];
            for(int j = 0;j < l2;++j)
            {
                array[i][j] = new T[l3];
            }
        }
    };
    T** operator[](int i){
        return array[i];
    }
};
```

and the memset use.

```
CArray3D<int> a(3,4,5);
// initialize array a with for-loop
memset(a[1],-1 ,20*sizeof(int));
//try to print it with for-loop but met memory access problem
memset(a[1],-1 ,20*sizeof(int));    
memset(a[1][1],0 ,5*sizeof(int));
```

Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xffffffffffffffff)

I'm debuging it in mac arm with clang++ lldb.

and I didn't meet the problem when using built-in 3D array a[][][] in same test code.

Comment: When you make the first `memset()` call, it looks like you try to assign `-1` to some memory, starting at `a[1]`. Since `a[1]` returns a `T**`, you are writing `-1` as a pointer. I assume that is not what you mean to do. Can you describe what you are trying to do? Are you trying to initialize the full array with the values `-1`?

Comment: First, there is NO array at all in what you are doing. You are simulating a 3D array using a *pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer-to* `T`. Your issue is `new T**[l1]` and `new T*[l2]` allocate pointers. Only `new T[l3]` allocates storage for `int` in your example. Your object is `3` allocated pointers where each pointer holds the address of a block of `4` allocated pointers, where each of those pointers hold the address to a block of memory for `5` `int`. `a[1]` addresses only `32` bytes. `20*sizeof(int)` attempts to set `80` bytes -- not going to work.

Comment: I try to write interger -1 into a[1][0][0] - a[1][3][4] ,this function does well in the built-in 3Darray a[3][4][5]

Comment: Why not just do `int a[3][4][5]; memset(a, -1, 3*4*5*sizeof(int));`? Why do you need a `CArray3D` class?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin but a[1] is a pointer to a continuously allocated memory,just like built in int[][] arrays in the c++ are implemented by pointers，does it means I need to change the pointer type into array pointer like int(*)[]

Comment: @ShaneBishop well....its a lab of my course

Comment: Your lab specifically asks you to create a `CArray3D` class? Or is that just something you chose to do?

Comment: @ShaneBishop yes.Actually it's recommended in lab to use nested and composite classes to instantiate the 3D array,but I also meet memory access problem as the memory allocated to composited object(2DArray) isn't continuous

Comment: You could do it the easy way and just use `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>`

Comment: @andrew_lau - No. With built-in `int[][]` the pointer arithmetic is completely different. `int[][]` is an *array-of-arrays* so `*(a + 1)` (equivalent to `a[1]`) is offset columns number of `int` from `a`. With the *pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer* the offset for `*(a + 1)` from `a` is `sizeof(a_pointer)`.